# XCode Simulator and Actual Device shows Different UI

Tags: swift, xcode

I've run into an issue and I'm hoping you can help me out! So as it turns out, for the first time I'm experiencing an issue where the UI of my actual iPhoneX device looks different to that of my XCode's simulator. Below is an image of this:

[Left is the actual device, and Right is the simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4zVT.jpg)

One golden bordered box is the only victim to this issue. I've tried restarting the computer and the phone, and I've also updated my phone and my XCode to the latest available. Similar issue with an iPhone 6. I've put the code for the problem UIImageView which is called **searchBack**. Its size is based on the device's display size and its position is different for iPhones and iPads:

```
searchBack = UIImageView(frame:CGRect(x:0, y:0, width: displayWidth*0.9, height: displayHeight*0.1))
if UIDevice.current.model.range(of: "iPad") != nil {
    self.searchBack.center = CGPoint(x: self.displayWidth*0.5, y: self.displayHeight*0.255)
} else {
    self.searchBack.center = CGPoint(x: self.displayWidth*0.5, y: self.displayHeight*0.207)
}
searchBack.image = UIImage(named: "searchBar Borders.png")
searchBack.contentMode = .scaleToFill
self.view.addSubview(searchBack)
```

Your help is greatly appreciated! Chrz in adv

Comment: Hello, can you add more details on how you create the border or some code snippets?

Comment: @GeorgeBafaloukas Added the snippet, and also accidentally found a solution. If you can help me understand it, that would be seriously awesome

Comment: Where is that code placed? ViewDidLoad? I would suggest using autolayout instead of calculating the sizes like that. Additionally the width of the superView will sometimes be different of the actual screen size at that point. This happens because the view has not calculated the actual screen size yet on viewDidLoad. This happens later in the view lifecycle.

Answer (score 0):

Alright guys, turns out while I was trying to figure out what was happening, I randomly commented the block of code below, I ran it, then uncommented it, ran it again, and the issue was resolved.

```
    if ( UIDevice.current.model.range(of: "iPad") != nil){
        self.searchBack.center = CGPoint(x: self.displayWidth*0.5, y: self.displayHeight*0.255)
    } else {
        self.searchBack.center = CGPoint(x: self.displayWidth*0.5, y: self.displayHeight*0.207)
    }
```

If some can please explain to me why this happens that would be AMAZING, so that I can prevent wasting hours on something like this next time.

Answer (score 0):

Where is that code placed? ViewDidLoad?

I would suggest using autolayout instead of calculating the sizes like that. Additionally the width of the superView will sometimes be different of the actual screen size at that point.

This happens because the view has not calculated the actual screen size yet on viewDidLoad. This happens later in the view lifecycle.

If you use autolayout to scale and position your view properly, the engine will calculate the sizes based on the constraints you put in for all different devices.

Again you could have some logic to set different constraints for iPads or you could use the "Device Traits" that iOS provides that will help you identify different screen categories and orientations.

I would appreciate if that helps you understand the issue to accept it as an answer.

Thanks!

Comment: Definitely! But are we able to automatically have small changes/differences in constraints between say iPhone 7 & iPhone 7 Plus? If so, could you please direct me to a link?

Comment: Take a look on the bellow for documentation:
https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/visual-design/adaptivity-and-layout/

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitraitcollection

Comment: So if you want your layout to work fine on all the devices I suggest using the safe layout guides and having proportional constraints to the width or the height of the superview. That way, you leave the calculations to the AutoLayout engine. That might help as well
https://useyourloaf.com/blog/proportional-spacing-with-auto-layout/